# Deleting a Many-to-Many Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework

I have three tables:-

SecurityRole & Groups & SecurityRoleGroups. (securityrole can have many groups. and a group can have many securityroles)

where the SecurityRoleGroup table is a many-to-many relation table, and Entity framework will not map this table . so i want to remove all the SecurityRoleGroup records that belong to certain SecurityRole. if i write something  as

```
SecurityRole securityrole = FindAllRole(id);

tms.SecurityRoles.Remove(securityrole).Groups.Where(a=> a.GroupID == group.GroupID)
```

will it remove only the needed records from the SecurityRoleGroup, ot it will also remove the related SecurityRole record ?

**:::UPDATE:::**

But what if I want to delete the Many-To-Many record only incase it is inside the currentGroups[c] array. can I write something as follow:-

```
 if (group.GroupID == currentGroups[c])
                            {
var securityrole = tms.SecurityRoles.Where(a => a.SecurityRoleID == id).Include(p => p.Groups).SingleOrDefault();

    (securityrole != null) {

    securityrole.Groups.Remove(group);

                                }
                            }
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. `Remove` returns a `bool`. Related entities are not removed if you remove them from a many-to-many collection.

Comment: I know , I want to remove the M-to-M records.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only the relationships stored in the link table, not the entities `SecurityRole` and `Group`s, the entities must be attached to the context in the current relationship (i.e. the `Group`s must be in the `Groups` collection of the `SecurityRole` entity) and then you must remove them from this collection. EF will track this change and write DELETE statements to the link table alone.

It can be achieved like so:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var securityRole = context.SecurityRoles
        .Include(s => s.Groups)  // or Include("Groups") for EF <= 4.0
        .SingleOrDefault(s => s.SecurityRoleId == givenId);

    if (securityRole != null)
    {
        securityRole.Groups.Clear();
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to remove only link records that fulfill a given condition use `Remove` instead of `Clear`:

```
    if (securityRole != null)
    {
        foreach (var group in securityRole.Groups
            .Where(g => currentGroups[c].Contains(g.GroupID)).ToList())
        {
            securityRole.Groups.Remove(group);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

(assuming that `currentGroups[c]` is a collection of group IDs)

Comment: @JohnPeter: See my Edit above.